# What are drawbacks of using aura design tokens in lightning web component

Tags: slds, design-tokens

**Tokens**

```
<!--tokens-->
<aura:tokens>
<aura:token name="testBgColor" value="#e7e7e7"/>
</aura:tokens>
```

**Aura Wrapper**

```
<aura:component description="auraWrapper" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <c:lwcTest/>
</aura:component>
```

My question is related to loading aura component or in other word wrapping up Lightning web components in aura component. 
Won't loading aura component affect performance in any way?
If I don't want to use design tokens mechanism, what are other options to have a common shared css? I understand there is no mechanism for having common/shared css because of shadow dom.

**lwcTest.html**

```
<template>
   <div class="test">Hello World</div>
</template>
```

**lwcTest.css**

.test {
        background-color: var(--lwc-testBgColor, red);
    }

Comment: If you can wait for Winter '20, there will be a way to import shared styles in LWC: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lwc_css.htm

Comment: Thanks @JohnTowers